# What is Google's Cloud Speech API's retention policy?

Tags: voice-recognition, privacy, google-cloud-speech, privacy-policy

When my users record their voice using the Google's Cloud Speech API, how can I give them the option to delete them later? I tried to search everywhere but haven't found it yet. Google seems to allow this within their Assistant App, but what about developers building something similar?

Similarly, what is the retention policy for these recordings? I need to be able to tell my users something, too.

Answer (score 0):

Why not read [their terms](https://cloud.google.com/terms/data-processing-terms)?

Regarding customer deletion of data (section 6.1)

> Google will enable Customer to delete Customer Data during the Term in a manner consistent with the functionality of the Services. If Customer uses the Services to delete any Customer Data during the Term and that Customer Data cannot be recovered by Customer, this use will constitute an instruction to Google to delete the relevant Customer Data from Google’s systems in accordance with applicable law. Google will comply with this instruction as soon as reasonably practicable and within a maximum period of 180 days, unless EU or EU Member State law requires storage.

It does not state a retention policy, though you should be able to contact them and get a definitive answer.

Comment: Thanks.  I did see that but I wasn't clear if that applies to the cloud speech api as well.  Especially since I couldn't find any documentation about any APIs for data deletion here https://cloud.google.com/speech/docs/apis  Is there a way to contact them?